# SQL select max value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like below:

```
Select Lname, MAX(HOURS)    
From (Select E.LName, SUM(Hours) as HOURS    
From WORKS_ON W    
     JOin EMPLOYEE E on E.SSN=W.ESSN    
Group by E.SSN) as hours
```

The answer is like:

```
Lname MAX(HOURS)

Black 55
```

From DB 55 is right answer for the max hour. But Black is not working 55 hours, it is another man called Grant. It seems like I have an answer that do not relate to each other. What should I do in order to get like:

"Grant 55" as an answer.

Comment: maybe, u can explain what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: please add info about your tables ...

Comment: Please provide some sample data or create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select E.LName, SUM(Hours) as HOURS    
From WORKS_ON W    
   JOin EMPLOYEE E on E.SSN=W.ESSN    
group by E.LName
ORDER BY HOURS desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I've got a result: Black 604, I think I need to add group by to your code

Comment: @NurdauletKenges, yes, of course a GROUP BY is required... I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming distinct LName,SSN in the E table

```
Select 
    E.LName
    ,SUM(Hours) as HOURS    
From 
    WORKS_ON W    
    JOin EMPLOYEE E on E.SSN=W.ESSN 
GROUP BY
    E.SSN
    ,E.LName   
ORDER BY 
    E.LName
```

You may want to change the order by clause according to your requirement.